# Python programming - numpy polyfit saying NAN

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I am having some issues with a pretty simple code I have written. I have 4 sets of data, and want to generate polynomial best fit lines using numpy polyfit. 3 of the lists yield numbers when using polyfit, but the third data set yields NAN when using polyfit. Below is the code and the print out. Any ideas?

Code:

```
###all of the 'ind_#'s are the lists of data. Below converts them into numpy arrays that can then generate polynomial best fit line###

    ind_1=np.array(ind_1, np.float)
    
    dep_1=np.array(dep_1, np.float)
    
    x_1=np.arange(min(ind_1)-1, max(ind_1)+1, .01)
    
    ind_2=np.array(ind_2, np.float)
    
    dep_2=np.array(dep_2, np.float)
    
    x_2=np.arange(min(ind_2)-1, max(ind_2)+1, .01)
    
    ind_3=np.array(ind_3, np.float)
    
    dep_3=np.array(dep_3, np.float)
    
    x_3=np.arange(min(ind_3)-1, max(ind_3)+1, .01)
    
    ind_4=np.array(ind_4, np.float)
    
    dep_4=np.array(dep_4, np.float)
    
    x_4=np.arange(min(ind_4)-1, max(ind_4)+1, .01)

###Below prints off the arrays generated above, as well as the contents of the polyfit list, which are usually the coefficients of the polynomial equation, but for the third case below, all of the polyfit contents print off as NAN###

    print(ind_1)
    
    print(dep_1)
    
    print(np.polyfit(ind_1,dep_1,2))
    
    print(ind_2)
    
    print(dep_2)
    
    print(np.polyfit(ind_2,dep_2,2))
    
    print(ind_3)
    
    print(dep_3)
    
    print(np.polyfit(ind_3,dep_3,2))
    
    print(ind_4)
    
    print(dep_4)
    
    print(np.polyfit(ind_4,dep_4,2))
```

Print out:

```
    [ 1.405  1.871  2.713 ...,  5.367  5.404  2.155]
    
    [ 0.274  0.07   0.043 ...,  0.607  0.614  0.152]
    
    [ 0.01391925 -0.00950728  0.14803846]
    
    [ 0.9760001  2.067      8.8       ...,  1.301      1.625      2.007    ]
    
    [ 0.219      0.05       0.9810001 ...,  0.163      0.161      0.163    ]
    
    [ 0.00886807 -0.00868727  0.17793324]
    
    [ 1.143      0.9120001  2.162     ...,  2.915      2.865      2.739    ]
    
    [ 0.283  0.3    0.27  ...,  0.227  0.213  0.161]
    
    [ nan  nan  nan]
    
    [ 0.167  0.315  1.938 ...,  2.641  1.799  2.719]
    
    [ 0.6810001  0.7140001  0.309     ...,  0.283      0.313      0.251    ]
    
    [ 0.00382331  0.00222269  0.16940372]
```

Why are the polyfit constants from the third case listed as NAN? All the data sets have same type of data, and all of the code is consistent. Please help.

Comment: Could you show us the whole of the arrays for which it fails? The example doesn't narrow it down enough either, you know that ind_1 and dep_1 work, so could you do polyfit(ind_1, dep_3, 2) and polyfit(ind_3, dep_1,2)?

Could you also plot the data so we can see wht it looks like?

Comment: You must have a bad data value in ind_3 or dep_3. Could you put the data somewhere so people can try? I used the values of ind_3 and dep_3 that you printed and got no problems. Also, in the interest of clarity perhaps you can cull all the other examples and focus only on the one that doesn't work.

Comment: I tried what will said, and found that the NAN polyfit results from the dep_3 array. The data set has several thousand entries. How can I get it to you? In the meantime, could you recommend anything I could try, like searching for type issues or maybe something I haven;t thought of to search the array for the invalid entry? Thanks

Comment: I have uploaded both data sets (so you can use the above code if you remove the 1,2,4 set code).                                                          ind_3 data set is here: http://www.filedropper.com/baddatasetind3                                                 dep_3 data set is here: http://www.filedropper.com/baddatasetdep3

Answer (score 21):

Just looked at your data. This is happening because you have a `NaN` in `dep_3` (element 713). You can make sure that you only use finite values in the fit like this:

```
idx = np.isfinite(ind_3) & np.isfinite(dep_3)
print(np.polyfit(ind_3[idx], dep_3[idx], 2))
```

As for finding for bad values in large datasets, numpy makes that really easy. You can find the indices like this:

```
print(np.where(~np.isfinite(dep_3)))
```

Comment: Thank you tiago. I used your first two lines and now it is working properly. I'll manually fix the nan.