# How do you remove corresponding x values of missing y-data from lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib, plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #for graphing data
import numpy as np

plt.figure()

x = col1 = [2011.005, 2012.6543, 2013.3456, 2014.7821, 2015.3421, 2016.7891, 2017.0173, 2018.1974]
col2 = [1.4356, "", 5.32245, 6.542, 7.567, .77558, "", ""]
col3 = [1.3345, 2.345, "", 5.356, 3.124, 6.12, "", ""]
col4 = [0.67, 4.235, "", 6.78, "", "", 9.56, ""]

plt.plot(col1, col2, label="Sample 1")
plt.plot(col1, col3, label="Sample 2")
plt.plot(col1, col4, label="Sample 3")
```

When I plot this graph the y-axis looks very off. Realising I need to remove the "" spaces in the list,
I tried this method:

```
x1 = []
y1 = []
for index in range(len(col2)):
    if (col2[index] != ""):
        y1.append(col2[index])
        x1.append(col1[index])

x2 = []
y2 = []
for index in range(len(col3)):
    if (col3[index] != ""):
        y2.append(col3[index])
        x2.append(col1[index])

x3 = []
y3 = []
for index in range(len(col4)):
    if (col4[index] != ""):
        y3.append(col4[index])
        x2.append(col1[index])

print(x2) #showed that there were 9 values for x2 and 5 values for x1
print(y2)

plt.plot(x1, y1, "b.", linewidth = 1, label="Sample 1")
plt.plot(x2, y2, "g.", linewidth = 1, label="Sample 2")
plt.plot(x3, y3, "k.", linewidth = 1, label="Sample 3")

plt.title("Testing", fontsize=16)

plt.show()
```

This showed me a dimensional error.
I don't know how to only extract the corresponding values of x to the y values.

Comment: say for col 2 and x, (2012.6543, " ") becomes (2012.6543, nan) and therefore not show up as a plot?
I'm so sorry, I'm new to python so everything seems overwhelming

Comment: I think I'm gooing to try and use pandas

Comment: Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: I tried importing pandas but it doesn't seem to work and the instructions on how to do this seem to clash too. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas' `pd.to_numeric(..., errors='coerce')` to convert each of the strings in the lists to ['nan'](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.nan).  (Numpy's `np.genfromtxt(np.array(..., dtype=str))` does something similar, but also removes the empty strings).

`nan` values will be skipped while plotting. Matplotlib puts its list of x-values next to the corresponding y-values, e.g. `2011.005, 1.4356` for the first pair and `2012.6543, np.nan` for the second. Each pair that has one or two `nan` values will not be plotted.

Here is some example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

col1 = [2011.005, 2012.6543, 2013.3456, 2014.7821, 2015.3421, 2016.7891, 2017.0173, 2018.1974]
col2 = [1.4356, "", 5.32245, 6.542, 7.567, .77558, "", ""]
col3 = [1.3345, 2.345, "", 5.356, 3.124, 6.12, "", ""]
col4 = [0.67, 4.235, "", 6.78, "", "", 9.56, ""]
col1 = pd.to_numeric(col1, errors='coerce')
col2 = pd.to_numeric(col2, errors='coerce')
col3 = pd.to_numeric(col3, errors='coerce')
col4 = pd.to_numeric(col4, errors='coerce')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(col1, col2, "b.", linewidth=1, label="Sample 1")
plt.plot(col1, col3, "g.", linewidth=1, label="Sample 2")
plt.plot(col1, col4, "r.", linewidth=1, label="Sample 3")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

It is unclear how your csv file looks like. The following example supposes the file looks like `csv_as_str`.  (`StringIO` is a function that lets you mimic a file with a string, so it is easier to add to a post. Reading from a file would just be `df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')`.)

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv_as_str ='''
col1,col2,col3,col4
2011.005,1.4356,1.3345,0.67
2012.6543,,2.345,4.235
2013.3456,5.32245,,
2014.7821,6.542,5.356,6.78
2015.3421,7.567,3.124,
2016.7891,0.77558,6.12,
2017.0173,,,9.56
2018.1974,,,
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_as_str))
```

Then the dataframe already has `nan` for the empty spots:

```
        col1     col2    col3   col4
0  2011.0050  1.43560  1.3345  0.670
1  2012.6543      NaN  2.3450  4.235
2  2013.3456  5.32245     NaN    NaN
3  2014.7821  6.54200  5.3560  6.780
4  2015.3421  7.56700  3.1240    NaN
5  2016.7891  0.77558  6.1200    NaN
6  2017.0173      NaN     NaN  9.560
7  2018.1974      NaN     NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I have edited the first version to my CSV and it looks correct! Thank you so so very much! I spent 3 days trying to code this, thought I was done and couldn't format the ticks. That's when I clocked that my code was wrong. I can't express how grateful I am!

Comment: Hi, sorry for bothering you again, but do you know how to add multiple linear regression lines to this data? I've tried 
x0 = np.array(x)
y0 = np.array(y1)
m,b = np.polyfit(x0, y0, 1)
print(b)
print(m)
plt.grid()
plt.plot(x0, m*x0 + b)

but m and b show up as nan

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647172/numpy-polyfit-doesnt-handle-nan-values

Comment: I'm getting nan for m2, b2, m3, b3. I've edited this page to show what I've written.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually what you want to do is iterate over the two arrays in question and only plot values where both array have "data". There are more elegant ways of doing this (see @JohanC), but in you may get some value by reviewing something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #for graphing data
import numpy as np

plt.figure()

x = col1 = [2011.005, 2012.6543, 2013.3456, 2014.7821, 2015.3421, 2016.7891, 2017.0173, 2018.1974]
col2 = [1.4356, "", 5.32245, 6.542, 7.567, .77558, "", ""]
col3 = [1.3345, 2.345, "", 5.356, 3.124, 6.12, "", ""]
col4 = [0.67, 4.235, "", 6.78, "", "", 9.56, ""]

## -------------------------
## pair up the arrays we want to work with.
## This will make it a little easier to deal with them programatically
## -------------------------
work_items = [
    [col1, col2],
    [col1, col3],
    [col1, col4],
]
## -------------------------

for work_index, work_item in enumerate(work_items):
    input_col1 = work_item[0]
    input_coln = work_item[1]
    plotting_col1 = []
    plotting_coln = []
    plotting_name = "Sample %s" % work_index

    for index, col1_value in enumerate(input_col1):
        coln_value = input_coln[index]

        if col1_value == "" or coln_value == "":
            # we are not interested in plotting this pair
            continue

        plotting_col1.append(col1_value)
        plotting_coln.append(coln_value)

    plt.plot(plotting_col1, plotting_coln, "b.", linewidth = 1, label=plotting_name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!